# Style tag links

Tags: tags

How can I style tag links in articles and in the popular tag module?

The tag manager lets me insert custom css classes for the tag link in articles, but this does not seem to work, as in no class gets inserted in the a element of the tag link.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of 2 things (that is if the options are not working for you).

1 is to create a template override, this can be done in joomla 3.x by going into the template manager then go to templates. Here select the template you are using and go to overrides and select the modules/components you want to override. With the override you can adjust the html as you want, adding the classes you want.

2 you can just "find" the element without a class, something like `div.the_class ul>li>a` can get to your anchor without needing a class.

These are just alternate ways if the class options do not seem to work for you.

Make sure to check your global configuration as well, for tags/articles (as well as the actual module using it).

Comment: Thanks, I managed to assign my class to the tag links in the popular module with the override method, now how can I do the same with the tag links in the article?

Comment: Article views can also have an override, although be careful with overrides on it since updates to Joomla can mess with it a little (there could be changes/additions that would force you to "redo" the override).

Comment: Thanks I managed to do what I wanted overriding article.php